# How to scale an image which should not smaller than a specified size

Tags: android, imageview, scale

I'm using a ImageView to dislay an image. There is a "Image--" button, when I click it, the ImageView will use a matrix to scale the image. The problem is, the image will finally too small to see.

You can see my examples.

Original Image:

[image]

After clicking button "Image--" 12 times:

[image]

You can see the sofa image is so small that hard to see now.

My "main.xml" content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/root" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- buttons -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:background="#336699"
               android:scaleType="matrix"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my java code is:

```
    this.btnImageZoomOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix(imageView.getImageMatrix());
            matrix.postScale(0.8f, 0.8f);
            imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            imageInfo();
        }
    });
```

My question is: how to let the sofa image will smaller a specified size? e.g. 1/5 of original size?

---

**UPDATE**

If I can get the size of scaled sofa image, it will be easy to check if the image is too small. But I tried a lot, still not get it, that's why I ask this question. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be easier to do it with Layoutparams (which will provide you the size of the image) instead of Matrix since you will need the size anyways. This could be your onClick method for zoom out:

```
  imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
  LayoutParams layoutParams=imageView.getLayoutParams();
  layoutParams.height*=0.8f;
  layoutParams.width*=0.8f;
  if(layoutParams.height>scaled_specified_size_in_px && layoutParams.width>scaled_specified_size_in_px){
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
  }
```

Notice that you need to have a scaled value there, OR you can simply limit it to a % of the original size (You will need to save the original size).

Comment: I need matrix type because I also have to do rotation on the image. But if that's too hard, I will just to rotate 90/180/270, that I can still use your solution. Now let me try.

Comment: Yea, you don't have to scale using layout params, but you can def get the size this way for check. (you won't need to set the scale type)

Comment: Can I still use matrix to scale? and use layout params get the size?

Comment: You should be able to. Give it a try and see if the layoutparams for w/h changes after you apply the matrix transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you check to see how big the 80% will make the photo, and if it is smaller than you want, dont do the scale? Maybe disable the shrink button if the size is too small?

Comment: The problem is I can't get the scaled image size from imageview. If I can get it, it will be an easy task.